# Delete jQuery UI dialog with surrounding content

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have some dialogs in AJAX-loaded content.  When the content is refreshed, the dialogs should be deleted; however, since jQuery moves them out of their original position in the DOM, they remain and start piling up.

A hack to fix this is to give those dialogs a specific class and explicitly destroy them in the AJAX code; however, this is "morally" incorrect.  What's the correct way to go about this?

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/6LPcS/

Answer (score 0):

You should call

```
 $('.yourdialog').dialog("destroy");
```

to remove the dialog

EDIT - if you need you can save the dialog in a variable and then call destroy on it

```
var dialog = $('.yourclass').dialog();

dialog.dialog("destroy");
```

Comment: This requires me to know the classes of the dialogs I'm destroying.

Comment: @YuriDelanghe you can save the dialog in a variable and call destroy on that

Answer (score 0):

Why not just check if they exist before adding them?
For example, do something like this:

```
var isDialogInitialized  = false
function verifyDialog()
{
   if (!isDialogInitialized)
   {
      //Init the dialog
      //...
      //Some other code

      //Set the flag to true
      isDialogInitialized  = true;
   }
}
```

Just make sure you call this function every time you create the dialog today. This way you'll be sure that the dialog is initialized only once.

Comment: The dialog could change between requests.

Comment: What do you mean by change? The content? How many dialog do you have? What make them unique?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think it is possible to do it in any 'smart' way... Why cannot you just destroy it manually each time the content is refreshed?

Also note that all dialogs have automatically assigned class "ui-dialog-content" and you may use it to close all opened dialogs:

```
$('.ui-dialog-content').dialog("destroy");
```

Comment: I can, but that's a hack.  I don't want to destroy ALL dialogs, only those that originated from a specific div.

Comment: Are you displaying more than one dialog at any point in time? If so, I think the only option is to add some class to it (eg. the same as div id with some suffix) and then destroy all dialogs with this class. I know it may feel a little bit hacky, but I seriously doubt there's a better solution.